# nvidia optimus low-end graphics mode?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I've seen a lot of people in this situation, but every time the variables differ and so does the solution for it.

I think I have everything installed correctly. I have Nvidia GeForce 540M with Bumblebee drivers installed.

What happens is, every two times when Ubuntu starts it tells me it is running in low-end graphics mode. I say `OK` and it crashes at the next window. I just restart and it starts normally.

I've made:

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]:
```

and the answer was:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev ff)
```

Comment: How have you installed nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

At the interface which have "low graphics mode", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. After login, input:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

and it will go in to x window.  Input:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and choose `gdm` later. This method is using `gdm` to replace `lightdm`. Reboot.